Xcode Warning: Empty dSYM File Detected – 'dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info' (x86_64)
It seems that an empty dSYM file is being generated, which indicates there’s no debug information in the executable:
warning: (x86_64) /Users/alpeshrupapara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FancallProjects-gmultyobcovajpddlllklfsxmtzs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Fancall.app/Fancall empty dSYM file detected, dSYM was created with an executable with no debug info. 
Steps I’ve Tried
a) Checked Build Settings: I made sure that the Debug Information Format is set to DWARF with dSYM File for the Debug configuration.
b) Clean Build Folder: I used Product -> Clean Build Folder to clear the cache and rebuilt the project, but the warning persists.
c) Rebuilt for Different Architectures: I attempted building for both real devices and the simulator, but the issue only appears with the simulator (x86_64 architecture).
